# IFTTT Auto Retweet User's Post with Filter

Tags: twitter, if-this-then-that, javascript, retweet

I would like to create an Applet via IFTTT that automatically retweets a specific users' post when it contains a phrase.

I have so far connected the "Tweet by specific user" applet to "Post a tweet" and played {{LinkToTweet}} in the action field of "Post A Tweet", however I keep receiving an error that says "Tweet by Specific user cannot be paired with "Post a Tweet". Any idea for a workaround?

-Also, I thought about possibly just sending a notification to my phone so I could retweet manually, but I am unsure what JavaScript to use to filter with the phrase I am looking for.

Any help is appreciated.